Error in Crashlytics iOS with Azure Pipeline
I'm facing error while generating Crashlytics iOS build using Azure Pipeline.
Azure Pipeline Below
trigger:
 - NONE
pool:
  vmImage:  macOS-14
steps:
- script: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.3.app/Contents/Developer
  displayName: Set Xcode 15.3 as the default version
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'ClientA-Distribution-Certificate.p12'
    certPwd: 'xxxx'
    keychain: 'temp'
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'ClientAAdhocProvisioning.mobileprovision'
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    configuration: 'AdHoc'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/XYZ.xcodeproj'
    scheme: 'ClientA (dev)'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'

Error in pipeline below
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:4203018E-580F-C1B5-9525-B745CECA79EB, name:My Mac }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:macOS, name:Any Mac }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:058C2030-474A-4EB0-A97C-8C841FD68D63, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:65FB1F67-C846-41EA-B433-2F02DE351A0F, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:562BA0B8-AC54-4D13-AC5D-1C7B2AA8DAC1, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:241D4EA7-C361-46FD-9ED9-B1FDFA3280E6, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6F99011B-E876-40CF-B2AB-4D50F7408621, OS:18.0, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:16C7800A-9863-4E16-93C1-C8A7601D6FB6, OS:18.1, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6104A9F7-D3FC-4BD4-8763-58E263BD55B5, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:EDF56D8A-7505-4F67-A661-7B4327821F77, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A5EF54D3-D8B3-455E-AB2F-B7CFAA2B5234, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6C6BB1BA-DDFD-406A-9563-1F10A273FEED, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5F454CCD-C8FC-459B-A134-0BA30C73B2C9, OS:18.0, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C15EC4F6-4CE9-45AA-BF4A-CEA617E53107, OS:18.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4FA51A4A-8F96-477B-92F8-287178AC83AF, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CF0AE835-BF27-402F-A8F3-63C3D09629FB, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2D626872-6834-409A-8A8A-5F227A4CF254, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7D375167-6FF4-4786-B5B2-60B885BB0510, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3BAD6C4D-C2A8-4F40-945C-8F79BDA49092, OS:18.0, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1C8E5B11-6276-4BA8-8701-4E659B868E00, OS:18.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CDD4CB14-F22B-4A70-B959-4EF13D6CF3B6, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:121606FB-1AB1-4F37-A8BF-4DBCE07D7999, OS:17.2, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AB84A286-C262-4DE5-89C8-38B9C580D1F7, OS:17.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:59572875-0997-4AD5-A246-01C8CD47B696, OS:17.5, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6A4581BF-9BBC-413B-9482-D6C928DBE56F, OS:18.0, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AC63E0CA-3788-4DED-B0A1-FEDD35D278A5, OS:18.1, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
** BUILD FAILED **
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

Has anyone faced similar issue?
I've attempted the following methods; however, still encountering various errors:

Enabled verbose logging
Enabled debug logging at the pipeline level
Updated the runner to the latest version
Added multiple parameters as arguments in Xcode
Updated the Xcode version


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
